# Fourier Series Scaling $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2-1}\cos {nt}=-2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{4n^2-1}\cos {2nt}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I was reading a book where I saw the following $$\begin{align}\tilde f(t)&=\frac 1 {\pi}+\frac {\sin t} {2}+\boxed{\frac 1 \pi \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2-1}\cos {nt}}\\&=\frac 1 {\pi}+\frac {\sin t} {2}-\boxed{\frac 2 \pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{4n^2-1}\cos {2nt}}\end{align}$$.
I don't understand how the authors get the second box from the first one.

> The authors have written "The two series representations for $\tilde f(t)$ are equal because $(-1)^{2k+1}-1=-2$ and $(-1)^{2k}-1=0$."

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Book name: Mathematical methods(2nd ed.), Merle C. Potter, Jack Goldberg.

Page no.379

If this question has already been asked please send the link.

Comment: set $t=0$ to see that the two sums result in different values.

Comment: *The authors have written...* indicates that the first series should read $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\color{red}{-1}}{n^2-1}\cos nt$$ (and then the question becomes trivial, and my answer becomes irrelevant).

Comment: Thank you so much @metamorphy, such a silly mistake, l apologize.